# Dynamic number of fields with ACF in Wordpress? AKA let the user set how many of the fields does he need

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to add a custom promo content slider, and I'd like to add 3 custom fields for each slide on the page:

- The image
- The Headline
- The paragraph

However, I don't know how many slides the user will want, maybe it's 2, maybe it's 6.

How can I achieve this?

After that, I guess I just need a for loop to generate the slides.

I have ACF pro if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ACF used repeater field

Check demo link:https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/